# Extension form framework finisher not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I have created custom finisher to call API and send data to the server. Here is the code for this.

**Typoscript:**

```
    plugin.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
        200 = EXT:ApiCall/Configuration/Yaml/BaseSetup.yaml
        300 = EXT:ApiCall/Configuration/Yaml/FormEngineSetup.yaml
    }

    module.tx_form.settings.yamlConfigurations {
        200 = EXT:ApiCall/Configuration/Yaml/BaseSetup.yaml
        300 = EXT:ApiCall/Configuration/Yaml/FormEditorSetup.yaml
        400 = EXT:ApiCall/Configuration/Yaml/FormEngineSetup.yaml
    }
```

**BaseSetup.yaml**

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          finishersDefinition:
            ApiCall:
              implementationClassName: 
                  'Vendor\ApiCall\Domain\Finishers\ApiCallFinisher'
```

**FormEditorSetup.yaml**

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      ########### FORMEDITOR CONFIGURATION ###########
      prototypes:
        standard:
          ########### DEFAULT FORM ELEMENT DEFINITIONS ###########
          formElementsDefinition:
            Form:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  900:
                    selectOptions:
                      60:
                        value: 'ApiCall'
                        label: 'ApiCall'

                propertyCollections:
                  finishers:
                    90:
                      identifier: 'ApiCall'
                      editors:
                        __inheritances:
                          10: 'TYPO3.CMS.Form.mixins.formElementMixins.BaseCollectionEditorsMixin'
                        100:
                          label: "ApiCall"
                        110:
                          identifier: 'url'
                          templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                          label: 'url'
                          propertyPath: 'options.url'
                          propertyValidators:
                            10: 'NotEmpty'

            ### FORM ELEMENTS: INPUT ###
            Text:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'


            Password:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            AdvancedPassword:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            Hidden:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            Textarea:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            ### FORM ELEMENTS: SELECT ###
            Checkbox:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            MultiCheckbox:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            MultiSelect:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            RadioButton:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            SingleSelect:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            ### FORM ELEMENTS: CUSTOM ###
            DatePicker:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'


            ### FORM ELEMENTS: UPLOADS ###
            FileUpload:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

            ImageUpload:
              formEditor:
                editors:
                  1000:
                    identifier: 'ApiCallname'
                    templateName: 'Inspector-TextEditor'
                    label: 'ApiCall field name'
                    propertyPath: 'properties.ApiCallname'

          ### FINISHERS ###
          finishersDefinition:
            ApiCall:
              formEditor:
                iconIdentifier: 't3-form-icon-finisher'
                label: 'A Label that seems to be never used...'
                predefinedDefaults:
                  options:
                    url: ''
```

**FormEngineSetup.yaml**

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          finishersDefinition:
            ApiCall:
              FormEngine:
                label: "When is this label used? And for what?"
                elements:
                 # hier nochmal alle Felder
                 # ich habe keine Ahnung wofür diese sind aber ohne geht es nicht
                 # spontan würde ich behaupten das es tca configuration ist
                 # aber ich definiere keine Datenbank Felder ~ vielleicht ist das aber eine Option
                  url: {label: url, config: {type: input}}
```

**Set finisher.**

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: send
type: Form
identifier: contactform
label: 'Drop us a line and we''ll get back to you ASAP! Yes, we''re fast!'
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'New Inquiry'
      recipientAddress: example@gmail.com
      recipientName: 'Admin'
      senderAddress: '{email-1}'
      senderName: ' {text-1}'
      replyToAddress: '{email-1}'
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
  -
    options:
      subject: 'Inquiry - sender'
      recipientAddress: '{email-1}'
      recipientName: '{text-1}'
      senderAddress: test@gmail.com
      senderName: 'Admin'
      replyToAddress: test@gmail.com
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
    identifier: EmailToSender
  -
    options:
      pageUid: '21'
      additionalParameters: ''
    identifier: Redirect
  -
    options:
      url: 'https://api.example.com/setdata'
    identifier: ApiCall
```

In my finisher file, I tried to debug form data, but this not working. here is my finisher file code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ApiCall\Domain\Finishers;


use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\AbstractFinisher;

class ApiCallFinisher extends AbstractFinisher
{
    protected function executeInternal()
    {
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this);
        $values = $this->finisherContext->getFormValues();
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($values);die;
    }
}
```

both debug not showing, a form is being submitted. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks an advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your finisher must be moved before the redirect finisher.

After the redirect finisher is called, your code is being stopped to perform the redirect. ✌️